Python code for making a program that converts the entered text into a secret language
What I mean is that it should convert the entered text into a secret language text using a pattern. For example, I want it to work as:
If I entered "apple", it should get converted to "bqqmf". The pattern here is that each letter gets replaced by the next letter in the alphabet.
I tried using pandas library, but couldn't get what I wanted.
import pandas as pd
a = list(input("Enter: "))
s = pd.Series(a)
print(s)
b = pd.Series(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))

for i in range(0,len(s)+1):
    s[i] = b[i=1]
print(s)


Run the following code for inspiration import this, inspect; print(inspect.getsource(this))

FYI: If you want something harder to decode, you can always use encryption (such as with GNU Privacy Guard).

BTW, the usual names for what you're trying to do are Caesar or shift cipher.

def fun(string, k):
    res = ""
    for char in string:
        if 'a' <= char <= 'z':
            x = chr((ord(char) - ord('a') + k) % 26 + ord('a'))
        elif 'A' <= char <= 'Z':
            x = chr((ord(char) - ord('A') + k) % 26 + ord('A'))
        else:
            x = char
        res += x
    return res

string = input("Enter a string: ")
k = int(input("Enter the number of letters to shift: "))
result_string = fun(string, k)
print("Shifted string:", result_string)

Input:
Enter a string: Apple
Enter the number of letters to shift: 1

Output:
Shifted string: Bqqmf

Note: If you only need to replace the text with its next letter then you can remove input k and replace it with a constant value of 1

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's a caesar chipher. You can shift each character in string using simple for loop or generator expression then join them.
s = ''.join(chr(ord(i) + 1) for i in input("Enter: "))
print(s)

# Enter: apple
# bqqmf

The ord() function returns the ASCII value of a character, and chr() returns the character that represents a specified Unicode. The join() function is used to concatenate all the characters into a string.

That should do, have a look again python data structure;
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
import string
abc = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
print(abc)


in_ = input("input your word...\n")

print(in_)

new_word = []

for each_one in in_:
    index = abc.index(each_one)
    changed_index = abc[index+1]
    new_word.append(changed_index)
    
print(*new_word)

